# JSON array not populating all the listview items

Tags: php, android, json, listview

I have a php file that I'm using to send informations in json format to android, this is the code of the php file :

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$dbname="ltc";

$type=$_GET['type'];



$con= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$BD= mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$query=mysql_query("select * from posts where type='".$type."'");
$num=mysql_num_rows($query);


if($num>=1)
{
    while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {

        $output=$list;
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
        mysql_close();
    }
    else
    {
    echo "error";
    }
?>
```

the informations sent to android are listed below :

```
{"IDpost":"1","username":"you","FirstN":"Mounzer","LastN":"Yaghi","Content":"test1","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-03"}{"IDpost":"2","username":"boss","FirstN":"Marwan","LastN":"Geha","Content":"test2\r\n","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-05"}
```

Now in android I'm trying to populate a listview with some informations using the json array, the code in android is :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Posts extends Activity {
String type,firstname,lastname,email,number,username,content;   
HttpClient httpclient;
HttpPost httppost;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle gotBasket=getIntent().getExtras();
        type=gotBasket.getString("type_post");
       this.setTitle(type);

        setContentView(R.layout.addpost);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.38/LTC/Uploadposts.php?type="+type+"");
 try{
 nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type",type));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FirstN",firstname));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LastN",lastname));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content",content));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



 if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
 {

 entity=response.getEntity();
 if(entity !=null)
 {
    InputStream instream=entity.getContent();
 JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
 //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),jsonResponse.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 String retUser=jsonResponse.getString("username");
 String retcont=jsonResponse.getString("Content");
 String getf=jsonResponse.getString("FirstN");
String getl=jsonResponse.getString("LastN");
String dop=jsonResponse.getString("Dateofp");




try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("["+jsonResponse.toString()+"]");

    int jArrayLength = jArray.length();
    List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(jArrayLength);

    for(int i =0; i<jArray.length(); i++){

        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        listContents.add(json_data.getString("FirstN")+" "+json_data.getString("LastN")+"                   "+json_data.getString("Dateofp")+"\n\n"+json_data.getString("Content"));

    }

    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));

}catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag","Error parsin data "+e.toString());
}

 }}

 }//End of first try

 catch(Exception e)
 {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } // End of first catch



    } //End of oncreate bundle



      private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
       {


       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String line = null;
       try
       {

       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
       }
       }catch(IOException e)
       {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally
       {
        try{
            is.close();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }return sb.toString();



       }


} //End of Class
```

The point is, only the first row of the database table is populating the listview, what i mean is only the first item in listview is populating, it should be two items ( 2 rows from the database table )
Any help ?

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions! Look here instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

Just move `json_encode` outside of the `while` block:

```
$output = array();
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $output[] = $list;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

So you populate all the data in array, and then send it all at once after the loop.

Comment: What does `json_encode` produce? Also note that you have to change your Java code to be able to work with array of objects.

Comment: it's producing this :
[{"IDpost":"1","username":"you","FirstN":"Mounzer","LastN":"Yaghi","Content":"test1","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-03"},{"IDpost":"2","username":"boss","FirstN":"Marwan","LastN":"Geha","Content":"test2\r\n","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-05"}]

what should I change in java please help me

Comment: Right, this is what your JSON should look like. Now you have to adopt your Java code to make it use it properly.

Comment: Can you help me with the java code ? I'm new to android if you can tell me what to change please do it I'll really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're returning invalid json from what I see above. Do what [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) said in the php code.
After this, in your java code, you can convert the json string to JSONArray and by using the getJSONObject method, you can get access to each object in the array.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(convertStreamToString(instream));
int length = jsonArray.length();

for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
    JSONObject row = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    // Do whatever you want to do with the row object here
}
```

Comment: but you didn't change anything in my java code, all i need is to know what to change in the code to make my program work. Thank you

Comment: @moonwalker You just have to use the row object to populate your `listContents` variable and finally you've to clean up your code and remove unnecessary variables, multiple definitions etc.
It's so strange that you are unable to integrate my answer into your code.